# JS benchmarking for mongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, benchmarking

I am running `BenchRun` for `MongoDb` using `JS` benchmarking script provided [here](http://www.mongodb.org/about/contributors/js-benchmarking-harness/) .

The result was displayed as below

```
    {
        "note" : "values per second",
        "errCount" : NumberLong(0),
        "trapped" : "error: not implemented",
        "updateLatencyAverageMicros" : 10.119265452635265,
        "insert" : 0,
        "query" : 0,
        "update" : 45688,
        "delete" : 0,
        "getmore" : 0,
        "command" : 460
    }

rs0:PRIMARY> print( "threads: 2\t update/sec: " + res.update );
```

Can someone help me to interpret these results?

How can I benchmark my `mongoDB` based on these results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not have noticed on the very page you linked, the first sentence says:

> This benchRun command is designed as a QA baseline perf measurement tool, not designed to be a “benchmark”.

So the answer to "How can I benchmark my mongoDB based on these results" is "you can't".

Benchmark has to reflect the actual operations you will be doing.

The output you got back shows that you got 45,688 updates and 460 commands per second.  That's what the "note" field is telling you.  The average latency for updates was 10 microseconds.  There were no errors.

Comment: Thnx Asya..Could you suggest how to benchmark mongodb .. that would have helped me better

Comment: the best way would be with an app that simulates what your real production application will be doing - the shortest path to that could be doing a quick prototype of the app with instrumentation available to measure throughput and latency (though you can get throughput numbers from mongos itself via `mongostat` you can't get application latency numbers from anywhere except the client.